# How to show GridView during Page_Load?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that normally loads when a user clicks a View Report button. However, I now want to show the gridview while the page loads.

I tried calling the following method from the Page_Load event:

```
   protected void btnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            grvReport.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Master.ShowMessage(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

but it didn't work. Also tried calling `grvReport.DataBind()` from Page_Load to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you setting the grid data source?

Comment: It's an object data source, declared in the markup. Would you suggest I should try something like GridView.DataSource = mydatasource before DataBind on PageLoad?

Answer (score 0):

This seems too obvious, but does the gridview have visible="true"

Answer (score 0):

```
  If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
           btnView_Click(nothing,nothing)    
  End If
```

or

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
       grdNotes.DataSource = myDataSource
       grdNotes.DataBind()
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are binding to a null/empty DataSource...then the GridView will not show up. You probably need to set the EmptyDataText property to something so that you can at least display a message when there is nothing to bind to.